# How can I execute "window.scrollTo()" function when page is reloaded?

Tags: javascript

I just do study JavaScript and I want to execute `window.scrollTo()` function when page is reloaded, but it doesn't work.

```js
window.scrollTo(0, 200)
```

I know one way that worked:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
   window.scrollTo(0, 200);
},1)
```

but I don't want to try this. Is there another option? I want to get the scroll activity to happen when page is loaded.

Comment: Maybe `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => window.scrollTo(0, 200))`?

Comment: Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/how-to-make-javascript-execute-after-page-load 
You can execute a scroll event to any of the listeners mentioned as needed.

Answer (score -2):

```
window.document.body.scrollIntoView({block:'start',behavior:'smooth'})
```